# Manual Pixel Editing with Colors for Mac

Tags: gratis, osx, images

I want a simple application that lets me enter the X and Y for a pixel, and its color value. Then being able to save the resulting picture. In other words, a application with a dialog asking for X, Y, and color values. Then it plots this to make a final picture. Any free applications, or better, built-in application that let me do that? I'm running a Mac with OS X El Capitan.